# Swift(ネイティブ)からWebviewのJavascriptを実行させる方法

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode

webview内のJavascript以下をSwiftで書いたUIButtonで実行したいのですがお力をお借りできないでしょうか？

Javascript側

function show() 
  {
    alert("JavaScript実行"); ←これをSwiftで実行したい
  }

Swift側
import UIKit
import JavaScriptCore

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

```
var webView : UIWebView = UIWebView()
```

}

button.addTarget(self, action: "pushBtn:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func pushBtn(sender : AnyObject) {

```
    //ここでwebviewのfunction show()を呼び出すコードを書きたい

    //以下Swiftでのアラートメモ
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Swift"
    alert.message = "Swiftでのアラート"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

webviewは、UIWebViewの方(WKWebViewではなく)でしょうか。そのwebviewの入ったプロパティをどう宣言しているのかも書いてくれていないので、勝手に

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
```

のような形でプロパティとして宣言してあるものとしますが、まさにJavaScriptのコードを実行するためのメソッドがUIWevViewに存在します。
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
呼び出し時点で関数が定義済みであれば、関数を呼び出すこともできるので、このように書くだけですね。

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("show();")
```

Comment: 回答を書き込んでしまってから気が付いてしまいましたが、webview javascriptで検索するだけで殆ど同じ質問(と回答)が多数見つかりますね。失礼しました。

Comment: UIWebView!のようにImplicitlyUnwrappedOptionalを使うのは、@IBOutletにしたり、確実にviewDidLoadの中で初期化するという場合を除いては、使わない方が良いでしょう。ただし、プロパティ宣言で`var webView : UIWebView = UIWebView()`と使いもしないUIWebViewをインスタンス化して代入しているのなら、それは絶対にやめた方が良いです。UIWebViewのように高機能なviewのインスタンス化はかなりメモリを食います(すぐ解放されるにしてもメモリの割当と解放は馬鹿にならないコストです)し、どんな副作用があるかもわかりません。確実に必要な値で初期化できないのであれば、使いもしないインスタンス化を行うのではなく普通のOptional型にするべきです。

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさんご指導ありがとうございました。動作しました。
プログラミング初心者で動くことしか考えていませんでした。これから学んでいきたいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 多少なりともお役に立てたのであれば、嬉しいです。事後になってしまいましたが、QAサイトを利用する場合は、検索機能を十分活用した上で、(それでもダメなら)自分の場合はどう違うせいで既存のQAが活用できないかを書かれると、より早く解決に近づけるかと思います。何かと大変なこともあるでしょうが、頑張ってください。